# SignalR communication Testing

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, signalr

We are implementing signalr communication for our custom solution.
before moving to production, we are doing a test run to analyze the signal delays and hence to improve the performance.

In order to calculate delay, we are sending ISO utc string along with the data object being communicated.
on the recieving side we are calculating recieving utc date.

Problem : Recieving time stamp is smaller than the Sending time stamp. While in both case the date is utc.

I will appreciate, if some body can explain the reason behind this situation.

Note : Server is IIS on Windows Server 2019 and Implementation is done in .Net Core 3.1
Delay is 0 because in the java script it has been set to 0 in case on -ve value..

[image: Screenshot of the test app]

Comment: are the server and client clocks in sync? I mean, are they running on the same machine? otherwise it makes no sense to measure time in that way

Comment: server and client machines are different. server is hosted in data center and the client is running on local machine. but both clocks are synchronized and within same timezone. also we are using the utc time so, i think, it doesnot matter even if the clocks and time zones are different. but if this is not proper way then how to calculate transmisson delay of the signal. we need to do that as it is our basic requirement of the logic.

Comment: Yes, it does matters. UTC is just another timezone. Machine clocks should be syncronized to the nanosecond otherwise the UTC (or any other timezone) date time will not be the same for both machines. So that's not the way to go unless the clocks are syncronized. Have you seen [this](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/signalr/913/monitor-performance-signalr-applications) and/or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance)?

Comment: This is a problem of machines does not have exact same time. And also the sending date can be greater than received because he can register that datetime when the receiver returns that successfully received the message so he puts the send time greater than the receiver.

Comment: @Kiril1512 I somehow understand your point. but my confusion is that on both side I am reading utc date then there should not be any problem.

Comment: correction : I think, they way of get the exact utc was not ok. now I change it to work like var now = new Date(new Date().toUTCString()).toISOString(); after this change problem seems to be solved. I dont see this difference of the date, after running my test program for continoue 8 hours.